# Is there a way to set up a "https to http" middle in GCP?

Tags: java, http, google-cloud-platform, https

I hope this isn't a duplicate question.
I set up a simple Java server based on Grizzly in GCP. It is an HTTP server servicing requests on 8080. I have not been able to set up an HTTP**S** server (and I tried...) and the server (which responds publicly to postman, curl, etc.) cannot receive any requests from my public website, since the website is on HTTPS.
So when sending a request, this error obviously appears:

```
index.html was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

A (very...) naive attempt to just send a request to my endpoint using a link which has https and 443 results in:

```
 failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

So my question is - if I am unable to define an HTTPS server (due to my own limitations), is there a way to configure a middle vm which will receive the client request on 443, send it to my actual server on 8080, then relay the response back?

Comment: If you are able to deploy your Grizzly solution in a container, you may want to consider deploying it to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run). In so doing, Cloud Run will proxy traffic (your "middle VM") using a TLS (HTTPS) endpoint to your container that exposes an HTTP port 8080.

Comment: Use a Load Balancer in front of your VM, or use a proxy, like NGinx to handle your certificate on the VM. But I prefer the @DazWilkin solution, and to deploy on Cloud Run

Comment: The solution for your specific scenario would be to use an external HTTPS Load Balancer and HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs#docs) service within GCP is precisely dedicated to act as an intermediate.

To configure a Load Balancer specifically for your use case in [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs) you can follow these steps:

1. Configure the default zone.

```
gcloud config set compute/zone <your-vm-zone>
```

2. Create an Unmanaged Instance Group.

```
gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged create ig-us-c1
```

3. Add your VM to the previously created Instance Group.

```
 gcloud compute instance-groups unmanaged add-instances ig-us-c1 --instances=<your-instance-name>
```

4. Create an external ip for the Load Balancer.

```
gcloud compute addresses create <ip-name> \
    --ip-version=IPV4 \
    --network-tier=PREMIUM \
    --global
```

5. Create a health check.

```
gcloud compute health-checks create http http-basic-check \
    --port 80
```

6. Create a backend service.

```
gcloud compute backend-services create web-backend-service \
        --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
        --protocol=HTTP \
        --port-name=http \
        --health-checks=http-basic-check \
        --global
```

7. Add the instance group as the backend to the backend service.

```
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend web-backend-service \
        --instance-group=ig-us-c1 \
        --instance-group-zone=<your-vm-zone> \
        --global
```

8. Create a URL map to route the incoming requests to the default backend service.

```
gcloud compute url-maps create web-map-https \
        --default-service web-backend-service
```

9. Create a target HTTPS proxy to route requests to your URL map.

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies create https-lb-proxy \
        --url-map=web-map-https \
        --ssl-certificates=www-ssl-cert
```

Note: The [SSL Certificates] can be [Self managed](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs) or [Google managed](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs); for testing purposes you can take a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#createresource) describing the usage of self-managed SSL certificates.

10. Create a global forwarding rule to route incoming requests to the proxy.

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create https-content-rule \
        --load-balancing-scheme=EXTERNAL \
        --network-tier=PREMIUM \
        --address=<ip-name> \
        --global \
        --target-https-proxy=https-lb-proxy \
        --ports=443
```

11. Create a DNS zone and record pointing to the Load Balancer external ip address.

```
gcloud beta dns managed-zones create example-zone --description="" --dns-name="example.com." --visibility="private" --networks="default"
gcloud beta dns record-sets transaction start --zone="example-zone"
gcloud beta dns record-sets transaction add <lb-public-ip-address> --name="*.example.com." --ttl="300" --type="A" --zone="example-zone"
gcloud beta dns record-sets transaction execute --zone="example-zone"
```

You can test using the command: `curl https://<hostname.example.com>`